# Configure NGINX for web and mobile site redirection

Tags: redirect, nginx

We have defined two server objects, one for *example.com* and another for *www.example.com*. We want to automatically redirect user to the mobile website *www.example.com/m* if user is on mobile browser.

There are two different projects for mobile and web version of app deployed on tomcat and APIs are exposed via only the web version. The mobile project consumes the same web APIs so the root is common.

the configuration is :

```
server {
  #listen 80 is default
  listen          80;
  listen          443 ssl;

  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate /path/to/certificates/www.example.com.chained.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /path/to/certificates/example.com.key;

  location / {
    if ($http_user_agent ~* "(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows ce|xda|xiino") {
        return 301 https://www.example.com/m;
    }
        return 301 https://www.example.com;
  }

  location /m {

  }

  server_name example.com;
}
server {
  listen          80;
  listen          443 ssl;

  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate /path/to/certificates/www.example.com.chained.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /path/to/certificates/example.com.key;
  server_name www.example.com;
  if ($scheme = http) {
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
  }
  root            /usr/share/tomcat/webapps/ExampleApp;
  location / {

        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
         proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;
  }
}
```

This configuration works properly when :

1. example.com is entered from mobile
2. example.com or www.example.com from web

However it does not work when:

1. www.example.com is entered from mobile (it opens the web version instead of the mobile site).

How can we make it redirect to *www.example.com/m* when user enters www.example.com from mobile?

Answer (score 1):

You can implement your `if` condition with a rewrite within the `location /` block. The rewrite loop is avoided by adding a `location /m` block. For example:

```
server {
    ...
    server_name www.example.com;
    ...
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

    location / {
        if ($http_user_agent ~* ...) {
            rewrite ^ /m$request_uri last;
        }
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
    }
    location /m {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
    }
}
```

Notice that the trailing `/` on the `proxy_pass` is removed as an additional rewrite is not required.

Note also that the `ssl on;` directives should be removed from your config as they will enable SSL on all ports (even port 80). The `listen 443 ssl;` directive is sufficient to enable SSL on port 443 only.

Comment: Thanks @Richard, With your suggested Implementation the mobile client is unable to make API calls as all the API calls are rewritten to /m e.g. www.example.com/login is redirected to www.example.com/m/login. The APIs are not available at /m but at /. How can we resolve this? I tried the regex implementation but it did not work for me.

Comment: @MohammadAslam I wasn't sure which URIs you wanted to rewrite. If you are only looking to rewrite `/` to `/m` then use `rewrite ^/$ /m/ last;`. You probably don't need the `location /m` in that case - as there is no redirect loop.